# Category Ordering In Xceed PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, propertygrid, xceed

I am using **PropertyGrid of Xceed** to display characteristics of some elements. There are different categories for element like: General, Advanced, Others, Special. Here, I found that the Xceed's propertygrid sorts the category as well as property in alphabetical order. I was able to sort the properties inside the categories by using `[PropertyOrder(n)]`. I also wanted to sort the categories so, I tried using `CategoryOrder` like `[CategoryOrder("General", 0)]` but it shows the following error:

> Error 2   Attribute 'CategoryOrder' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class' declarations.

Am I using it wrong?
The code provide below is just a sample to show how I am using this.

```
[Category("General")]
[CategoryOrder("General", 0)]
[DisplayName("XValue")]
[Description("Value of X-Coordinate")]
[ReadOnly(true)]
[PropertyOrder(1)]

[Category("Advanced")]
[CategoryOrder("Advanced", 1)]
[DisplayName("Collision")]
[Description("Collision")]
[ReadOnly(true)]
[PropertyOrder(1)]

[Category("Others")]
[CategoryOrder("Others", 3)]
[DisplayName("Traffic")]
[Description("Traffic at a point")]
[ReadOnly(true)]
[PropertyOrder(1)]

[Category("Special")]
[CategoryOrder("Special", 2)]
[DisplayName("Special cases")]
[Description("Contains the special cases and files")]
[PropertyOrder(1)]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a sample on how it should be used:

```
[CategoryOrder("General", 1)]
[CategoryOrder("Advanced", 2)]
[CategoryOrder("Other", 3)]
public class MyClass
{
    [Category("General")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    [Category("Advanced")]
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
    [Category("Other")]
    public double Property3 { get; set; }
    [Category("General")]
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    [Category("Advanced")]
    public int Property5 { get; set; }
    [Category("Other")]
    public double Property6 { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick question.  I'm doing some dynamic type creation and while I'm properly setting the category attributes at runtime, I am not able to properly set their order.  Using the above code as an example, here's what I'm doing in code *prior* to assigning the `MyClass` instance to the `PropertyGrid` ... `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(MyClass), new CategoryOrderAttribute("General", 1), new CategoryOrderAttribute("Advanced", 2), new CategoryOrderAttribute("Other", 3));` but it is not working.  Any idea why?

Comment: BTW, I added this as a separate question here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/57550862/168179